# rememberLauncherForActivityResult throws Launcher has not been initialized in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-intent, android-jetpack-compose

When trying to invoke the Firebase Auth UI, using the below code the compiler throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Launcher has not been initialized. Not sure, why the launcher is not initialized

```
@Composable
internal fun ProfileUI(profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel) {
    val loginLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) { result ->
        if (result != null) {
         //do something
        }
    }
    if (profileViewModel.isAnonymousUser) {
        loginLauncher.launch(profileViewModel.buildLoginIntent())

    } else {


    }
}

    override fun buildLoginIntent(): Intent {

    val authUILayout = AuthMethodPickerLayout.Builder(R.layout.auth_ui)
        .setGoogleButtonId(R.id.btn_gmail)
        .setEmailButtonId(R.id.btn_email)
        .build()

    return AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        .setAvailableProviders(
            listOf(
                AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
            )
        )
        .enableAnonymousUsersAutoUpgrade()
        .setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setAuthMethodPickerLayout(authUILayout)
        .build()
}

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Launcher has not been initialized
at androidx.activity.compose.ActivityResultLauncherHolder.launch(ActivityResultRegistry.kt:153)
at androidx.activity.compose.ManagedActivityResultLauncher.launch(ActivityResultRegistry.kt:142)
at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher.launch(ActivityResultLauncher.java:47)
at com.madhu.locationbuddy.profile.ProfileUIKt.ProfileUI(ProfileUI.kt:37)
at com.madhu.locationbuddy.profile.ProfileUIKt.ProfileUI(ProfileUI.kt:15)
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As per the [Side-effects in Compose documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects):

> Composables should be [side-effect free](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model).
>
> Key Term: A side-effect is a change to the state of the app that happens outside the scope of a composable function.

Launching another activity, such as calling `launch`, is absolutely a side effect and therefore should never be done as part of the composition itself.

Instead, you should put your call to launch within one of the Effect APIs, such as `SideEffect` (if you want it to run on every composition) or `LaunchedEffect` (which only runs when the input changes - that would be appropriate if `profileViewModel.isAnonymousUser` was being driven by a `mutableStateOf()`).

Therefore your code could be changed to:

```
internal fun ProfileUI(profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel) {
    val loginLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) { result ->
        if (result != null) {
         //do something
        }
    }
    if (profileViewModel.isAnonymousUser) {
        SideEffect {
            loginLauncher.launch(profileViewModel.buildLoginIntent())
        }
    } else {
        // Output your UI, etc.
    }
}
```